# How to use assembly in Arduino?

Tags: led, assembly

I have been assigned a university project to make a sound/audio responsive LED using assembly language. I have already wrote C++ code in Arduino that uses the Fastled library.

How do I write working code for this project in assembly (not restricted  to @rduino IDE, but preferable)? I've already tried converting my code to assembly using an online converter, but it is useless.

Answer (score 10):

The Arduino IDE is quite idiosyncratic. It won't let you work on a
project that doesn't have a file with the extension “.ino”. On the other
hand, it doesn't care about how much code is in that file, and you can
keep it happy by creating an empty .ino file. I recommend however that
you put at least a comment block in that file, in order to make things
less confusing for other people who could see your project. Then you can
put your assembly code alongside this empty file, in files of their own
ending with the “.S” extension. These files will be preprocessed before
being assembled, so you can `#include <avr/io.h>` and use the macros
defined therein for the IO ports, bits, etc.

The project would look like this:

```
my_project/         # containing directory
├── my_project.ino  # comments only, to keep the IDE happy
├── my_project.S    # main assembly file
└── some_extras.S   # possibly more assembly files...
```

If the whole project is pure assembly, one of your assembly files should
define a symbol called `main`, which is the entry point of the program:

```lisp
.global main
main:
    ; code starts here
```

If you are going to mix assembly and C++, then you can define `main()`
in the .ino file, and call from there your assembly routines, which
should be declared as `extern "C"`:

```cpp
extern "C" void my_assembly_routine();

int main()
{
    my_assembly_routine();
}
```

Mind the [calling conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc) when mixing asm and C++ though.

If you are going to use the Arduino core library, then you should define
`setup()` and `loop()` instead of `main()`. The Arduino core will then
provide it's own `main()`, which takes care of its initialization.

If you are going to write mostly C++, with only some assembly sprinkled
here and there, *inline* assembly could be a better option. C.f. Michel
Keijzers' answer.

Comment: Upvoted, much new info for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry.

The main learning effect of this exercise is "Don't do it".
You won't beat the c++ compiler regarding performance (speed). But you will run into more errors than you can imagine.

The only purpose of manual assembler language inside c/c++ is to add nanosecond timing by adding some `asm("nop");` statements to wait a controlled small number of cpu clock cycles.
@Michel Keijzers' examples are already implemented. Even in Arduino's convenience environment.

IMO it's more challenging to get beyond Arduino programming by going directly to the MCU's hardware level, dealing with Timers, other MCU components, Registers etc. directly. In C/C++ of course. There you learn that there's much more that can be done beyond the Arduino environment.

Or: Look at compiled results via `avr-objdump` to learn how C++ is compiled to machine code by experts. Very eventually, you might notice how you could help the compiler optimizing.

Comment: 1. By learning assembly, you learn _a lot_ more than “don't do it”: you get an intimate understanding of what the compiler and the hardware do, and you learn what kind C/C++ constructs compile to efficient machine code. Also, you must have written at least _a little bit_ of assembly to really appreciate the compiler's job (the output of `avr-objdump`). 2. It is not rare that avr-gcc produces sub-optimal code, easily beaten by hand-crafted assembly. I guess this flavor of gcc has not been fine-tuned as much as the ARM or x86\_64...

Comment: @Edgar Bonet : Sure, you learn a lot more. And only after you've learnt that you can 1. appreciate what the compiler is doing for you 2. interpret its results 3. decide whether you'll continue with assembly programming. BTW: I came from assembly programming, because FORTRAN was not really optimal for small machines, and I'm happy since someone invented C and others built cross-compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Re: "The main learning effect of this exercise is "Don't do it". You won't beat the c++ compiler..."
I agree with Edgar Bonet:
(1) Arduino is about learning, including learning Assembler programming, hardware, etc.
And ...
(2) Yes, you can beat the C++ compiler with a little practice. E.g. the GNU tool-chain can input the C++ program and output the corresponding Assembler.
This can be very instructive for learning Assembler. You can then hand-craft any bit of that code...make it faster, or smaller
--o-0--

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `asm`  keyword, like:

```
asm("sei \n")
```

In your case it is advised to use defines, e.g.

```
#define CLI()          asm("cli \n")
#define noInterrupts() cli()

#define SEI()          asm("sei \n")
#define interrupts()   sei()
```

See more info at [arduino-inline-assembly-tutorial-1](https://ucexperiment.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/arduino-inline-assembly-tutorial-1/).

Comment: Which IDE do we have to use for this? Also, are these definitions for inline assembly? We are restricted to have the main working code of our program in assembly language.

Comment: Afaik the default Arduino IDE can be used for this. You probably have to put the code inside the setup and loop functions. Note however, the Arduino IDE creates some code around the setup and loop (like interrupt handling).

Comment: Wait a minute here. You can use `#define` for functions/methods? Well, that's new to me.